# Cannot save a BufferedReader to a file

Tags: python, http

I am trying to use `http-parser` and write the response to a file following the example [here](https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/). This is what I am trying to do, I changed the GET request to request an image and then trying to save it to a file:

```
open('image.jpg', 'wb').write(p.body_file().read())
```

But the file has zero bytes. What am I missing here?

Complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

from http_parser.http import HttpStream
from http_parser.reader import SocketReader

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('www.linux-mag.com', 80))
        s.send("GET http://www.linux-mag.com/s/i/topics/tux.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.linux-mag.com\r\n\r\n")
        r = SocketReader(s)
        p = HttpStream(r)
        print p.body_file()
        open('image.jpg', 'wb').write(p.body_file().read())
    finally:
        s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Works for me, I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: I just realized that I need to `sudo` the script. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to `sudo` the script. I did `sudo python <script>` it works fine.